# Alternatives for deprecated gtk_list_new() in gtk2?

Tags: c, linux, user-interface, gtk, gtk2

I am using GTK+ 2 and I need to make a listbox. However, the `gtk_list_new` method is apparently deprecated and should not be used in newly written code. I have seen some `gtk_list_box_new()` function, but I cannot use that because I am using GTK+ 2. No, I am not going to upgrade to GTK+ 3, because all my text entries become too fat. I have other reasons to only use GTK+ 2. What can I do to get a GTK+ 2 listbox? Should I use these "Deprecated" functions anyways, or if not, what are some good GTK+ 2 listbox functions? I am using the C programming language.

Another problem I have is that even if they do work fine in GTK+ 2, developer.gnome.org says almost nothing about how to use them.

Comment: There are not a lot of good reasons to use GTK+ 2 , when GTK+ 3 has been released 8 years ago, and GTK+ 4 should be released in 2019. The only one I can see is when you maintain a big legacy application that is supposed to die at some point, so not worth migrating. If you have problems with text entries in GTK+ 3, then ask a question about it, otherwise that's an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: About developer.gnome.org not saying a word on how to use them, that's because there's currently a bug in doc generator I think, that doesn't seem to be backward compatible. If you really really REALLY want to use GTK+ 2, just install devhelp on your machine, it will have the documentation for your version of GTK+, and should contain an older version of the GTK+ 2 doc that doesn't have this bug.

Comment: GTK+ 3 provides [GtkListBox](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkListBox.html). You can still use GtkList if you're sure you'll never migrate your application. Otherwise, you may prefer GtkTreeView, which exists in both versions, but is a bit hard to use.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the deprecation statement, the functions will always exist in GTK 2.

Comment: Any ways developer.gnome.org wont let me know howw to use them?

Comment: Use the documentation in the source for the version you are using. Not the online documentation.

Comment: could you please tutor me into using these functions since the html website wont tell me

Comment: What is "In the source"

Comment: The online documentation is generated from comments in GTK's source code. Read the comments in the source code.